# jQuery tabs scroll out of view when navigating long tab panels via named anchors

Tags: jquery, hash, tabs, scroll, scrolltop

Take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/contendia/GBTAS/

The idea is to keep the page friendly for non-js users by only creating tabs when js can run.  Otherwise, I want to present the page as just a stack of divs.  The list for the tabs is completely automated depending on the number of tabs and each tab is named according to the corresponding divs id attribute.

All is working well, but now I'm attempting to rework the click event to navigate the tabs more generally.  Before, I just looked for a click event on one of the list item tabs (li) and ran the necessary code to change the tabs.

But now I want to make this function more general so it works when a user clicks on any anchor with a hash value equal to one of the tabs IDs without having to target an actual tab.  I'm not sure exactly how to go about targeting a hash in an anchor and testing it against the tab IDs.  The function I've got works in FF and IE for both clicking a tab and clicking an anchor link (e.g., `<a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>`).  However, if the tab is longer than the veiwport, the top of the tab scrolls to the top of the window, causing the tab links to disappear.  The user must manually scroll the tab links back into view to navigate to another tab. I've tried .scrollTo() to move the page back into place, but with no luck.

Is this just an issue with .scrollTo or have I gone about the click function all wrong?

Would appreciate any ideas.  Bonus, would be great if it would animate.

http://jsfiddle.net/contendia/GBTAS/

Comment: Same issue here, using hash with tabs so the back-button works on drill-downs from within tabs etc. The hash seems to be what's causing it. I manually add the hash on tab select, so I can probably move the scroll position back to the top (where the tabs are) at the same time, as you suggest.

Did you come to a conclusion on this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here you go.. I hear you that this doesn't work for you, but it works perfectly for me. Here's the click handler which fires when they hit a tab link, and it adds the hash as you can see. Without the "scrollTo()" the scrolling is as you describe... with it, the problem goes away. I conclude then that setting the href for some reason scrolls the browser viewport.

```
j('#tabs ul li a').click(function () {
    location.hash = j(this).attr('href');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}); // Add click handler to set # in address bar
```

Comment: I can see where you're going with this,  but why set the hash in the address bar when you don't have to? I.e., it sets itself if you just add the target in the href like so href="#tab2". Also, `window.scrollTo(0,0)` isn't doing exactly what I need. Instead of pulling the tabs into view, it pulls the entire page to the top. So, I tried `$("div.autotab-container").scrollTo(0, 0);` which works somewhat, but still pushes the tabs above the viewport. Also, having the hash in the link doesn't make the back button work for me. The hash changes in the address bar, but the tabs do nothing. Suggestions?